# Given verbal offer from a company but about to start a large project at current company

Tags: professionalism, job-change, job-offer

I have been told by HR of a company that I have been interviewing with that they would like to extend me an offer and it will take 1-2 weeks to get approved.

I do not want to put in notice at my current position until I get the actual offer, but I am supposed to give a timeline presentation in two days on a multi-month project which will probably not be started if I leave (until they find a replacement).

Do I tell my manager (who I have a good relationship with) that I am going to be leaving or continue as if nothing was going to happen and present the timeline?

Comment: Continue, verbal offers mean nothing.

Comment: If the company you work for now will continue with the project when they hire your replacement, roll forward on the current job until the new one comes in.  It's helpful to leave your successor at the old employer any materials you've produced to date.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As long as you do not have a signed contract with a new employer, I would simply continue working at your old job as if nothing is happening. The potential offer might not work out, which would mean the multi-month project is still for you to finish. Pre-emptively starting to burn your bridges does not help you in any way. Once you sign your new contract, you can give notice and transfer the project to someone else. If this is not possible, this is the problem of your company, not yours.

Comment: You can always hand in a notice if the offer comes through, but you probably will have significant problems retracting your actions if you acted as if you are leaving.

Considering one is all loss, and the other one gives you no real downsides, you never leave a job until the other party gave you a real offer on paper.

Answer (score 6):

Don't tell, even though you have a good relationship.  It's still not a done deal and the risks if it falls through are too great ( at best you'd likely be sidelined off the big project, at worst your a dead man walking).

May seem hard, but you need to carry on as if nothing has happened until the new job is signed and sealed( or if you need to show your hand for references etc).

Answer (score 2):

Never give notice until you have an in writing start date with an offer letter. These can still be revoked, but its very rare. Start dates and verbal offers are verbal for a reason. Tell them you need this formally in writing before you can give your two weeks notice.

Do NOT risk telling your boss your leaving until you are gone. It is never worth the risk. Even if there is just a 1% chance that your job will fall through and/or the company will fire you. You need to look out for yourself.

Comment: I want to add one point. Verbal offers are not final. If its final you will get a written offer. Sometimes stuff gets delayed for whatever reason. Sometimes someone else in the company can put on a hiring freeze. I have seen people strung along.

Comment: Is a written offer legally binding or just less likely to be revoked because it is written?

Answer (score 1):

If you are a 'good catch' so to speak, you might want to let the new company know that you require a signed offer sooner than the two week timeline they have given you. A person with the right talent and good fit for the company shouldn't be kept waiting, and there is nothing wrong with letting them know that.

Comment: If anything, this will IMHO **increase** your value in the eyes of the new employer.